# Button > listview > new activity, any suggestions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

as you can see in the headline i my apps layout is like this right now Button > Listview > Activity
but i am having an issue with the activity.
I want to open a new activity when i click RR, faiz or any other list item.
here is my,

Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button devletbuton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    devletbuton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, devlet.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            Button bankabutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            bankabutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, banka.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);

                    Button makrobutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                    makrobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, makro.class);
                            startActivity(intent2);


                            Button hanebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
                            hanebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, hanehalki.class);
                                    startActivity(intent3);
                                }
                            });

                        }
```

My banka.java

```
public class banka extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView2;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.banka);
    listView2 =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("RR");
    arrayList.add("Capital");
    arrayList.add("Faiz");


    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        }
    }
```

**when i click button it opens listview and i want to open a new activity when i click RR, Capital or Faiz**

**THANKS BTW**

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String str = arrayList.get(position);
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, hanehalki.class);
    startActivity(intent3); 

}
});
```

Comment: Thanks man this helped, but now it's opens the same activity with all three RR,Capital,Faiz

Answer (score 0):

```
  listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        /**
         *
         * @param parent current ListView
         * @param view current item be clicked
         * @param position position of current item
         * @param id id of item be clicked
         */
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    // TODO: start new activity for click "RR"
                break;
                case 1:
                    // TODO: start new activity for click "Capital"
                break;
                case 2:
                    // TODO: start new activity for click "Faiz"
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }

    });
```

Comment: Please add some explaination

Comment: can you descirbe you question in detail?

Answer (score 0):

**MY SOLUTION** Created 3 new java and layout file and put this in my banka.java

```
listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RR.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
            }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), capital.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, 1);
                }

                    if (position == 2) {
                        Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), faiz.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myintent, 2);
                    }
                    ;
                }});}}
```

**full java here**

```
public class banka extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView2;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.banka);
    listView2 =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("RR");
    arrayList.add("Capital");
    arrayList.add("Faiz");


    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RR.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
            }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), capital.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, 1);
                }

                    if (position == 2) {
                        Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), faiz.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myintent, 2);
                    }
                    ;
                }});}}
```